# Is a lightweight database migration running with an app in background?

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

Is a lightweight database migration still running if the app runs in background on iOS5/iOS6 ?
If I start the migration, and then open another app, is the migration still going?

2.
Is it running when the phone is locked on the initial screen as well?

thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question. As far as I know and experienced, the migration runs (synchronously) when you call `addPersistentStoreWithType:...` with the migration options, or if you explicitly call `migrateStoreFromURL:...`

Comment: @MartinR Yeah, but what happens when you run the app, you run that line of code, and you open another app, or you switch the screen of your device off, is the migration running in background?

Comment: OK, now I understand your question!

Comment: @MartinR Is there a way to disable the device sleep mode? So the iOS never goes back to the lock screen interrupting the migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no Core Data migration running when the app is in the background.

Reason: When the user updates your app it will be closed and then updated. The database migration is then running with the first start of the app after the update.

**Edit:** So what happens when the user clicks the Home-Button during the migration process? I'd guess that Core Data stops and rolls back to a valid state (version) and may restart after the user opens the app again. But I'm not quite sure.

**Edit 2:** After thinking about that I'm almost sure that my suggestion is correct. During the migration the Core Data stack is not finally initialized and it will be stopped when the user clicks the Home-Button. So when the user returns to the app and the app accesses the `NSManagedObjectContext` the first time, the Core Data stack has to be build up again. But to be 100% sure, please try it in the Simulator and Device – it should be less effort to do.

Comment: Yes but what happens if I open the new updated app, the migration starts, and then for example, I lock the screen of the iPhone (screen is off). Is the migration still running in background? Or if I open another app for example.

Comment: ps. Is there a way to disable the device sleep mode? So that iOS never goes back to the lock screen interrupting the migration?